# Javascript calling this.function() with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, parameters

I'm currently developping in JS and I still have issues about OOP with JS. TBH I don't really understand how it works since it look like its really flexible but still really annoying in the syntax.

### So here's what I have :

```
function Object1(){

var x;
var y;

    Object1func1( param x, param y ){
        ///
    }
}

function Object2(){

var a;
var b;

   function Object2func1(){
    var obj = new Object1();
        obj.Object1func1( a, b );
        ///
    }
}
```

I have multiple "objects" in a single script, defined by functions, they have functions inside them and i need to call them with args, for example, i need to init an object that will init 2 others and call some of their own functions. I started doing this kind of syntax :

```
function Object1(){
    //Var here

    this.function1 = function function1(){
         do stuff here/
    }

...
}
```

Why would i do this ? Because i need to call this function inside and outside the current object, problem is, with this method i cant pass args from outside the object, and i saw it was a really bad way of coding, so i'm here to ask you the proper way to do this.

In java, for example, you just define a class, his functions, and thats all, easy, in JS, i really don't understand how to do this... quite confusing.

### What I need :

```
Object1(){

function1(arg a, arg b){}

}

function2(){
    function1( defaultA, defaultB );
}

OutsideObject(){
var obj = new Object1();

obj.function1(X,Y);
}
```

Thanks you.

EDIT : So i replaced my main object with the prototype stuff. I set all of his var public, using this.var in the 'constructor', but then, I cant access any of theses this.var in any MyObject.Prototype.function(). It say they are undefined :/

EDIT 2 : My problem seems to come from the "this", it looks like it change itself, how can I stick to a class variable and not something relative as 'this' seems ?

EDIT 3 : For "absolute" variables you have to declare them with "var" or even nothing, not "this.var", all the docs I read were telling that the difference was about the privacy, its not, Its also about getting the var in a relative or an absolute way, in my case, it got me stuck for hours because of this. Problem solved.

Comment: I recommend to read this MDN article: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: What do you mean, "*can't pass args from outside the object*"? What you started with seemed fine.

Comment: How is your `function2` supposed to work without an instance of `Object1`?

Comment: Its because i forgot a }, function1 and function2 are defined inside object1. Im gonna try the prototype way but since i only need to use my objects once I avoided this.

Comment: I'd say you have two choices; familiarize yourself with JavaScript's franken-patched object-orientation, or use some JS framework that grants more comprehensible object-orientation. Given that pure JavaScript coding is impressive, but oft-impractical, my preference for you is to try out an trans-compiling language like TypeScript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a method on all instances of a constructor function, make it a property of the constructor's prototype.

Define arguments on the function expression as normal.

```
function Object1(){
}

Object1.prototype.function1 = function function1 (x, y){
};

var obj = new Object1();
obj.function1(3,4);
```

Comment: It looks like its working but does the var from Object1(){ this.var } is supposed to be known of the function1 ?

Comment: @OrnaFulsamee Yes. If in the first block you wrote "this.myX = 3", you could access that same variable in the second block (and of course it would be object-specific)

Comment: I've tried with a random var and it worked, now i think that the problem comes from somewhere else, i call a function that works as a loop, this first time i think it works but then it fail because 'this.somevar' might change. Im gonna check this.

Comment: Alright, fixed, its because I had to declare the var in a private way 'var example' and not 'this.example'. Now I can call it in an absolute way with Object.var. I don't really understand the whole thing but I didnt found anything telling that on all of the doc I read. I have to calm down a bit.